# How do I get current ListViewItem with a control in ItemTemplate, WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, itemtemplate

I have the following code:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanelName="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBoxName="textBoxOrg"
            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{BindingOrgText}"
            IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <TextBoxName="textBoxNew"
            Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{BindingNewText}"
            AcceptsReturn="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now i want to get the parent control(ListViewItem) focused by using **textBoxNew_GotFocus**,but when I use textboxNew.Parent, it returns an error what "Can not convert DependencyObject to Control". what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can walk through the visual tree by using [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx).
The visual/logical tree concepts are quite central to the whole WPF experience. One good read is:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfElementTrees.aspx